# Android & Javascript - From two functions to one

Tags: javascript, android, android-gallery

MainActivity.java

```
public String URI = null;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        URI = pickedImage.toString();
    }
}

public String GetURI()
{
   return URI;
}
```

WebAppInterface.java

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void GetPicture()
{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    ((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
}

@JavascriptInterface
public String GetURI()
{
    return getRealPathFromURI(mContext, Uri.parse(((MainActivity) mContext).GetURI()));
}
```

I'm using the following Javascript functions

```
function GetPicture()
{
    Android.GetPicture();
}

function loadImage()
{
    document.getElementById("img").src = Android.GetURI();
}
```

The first one is used to get the picture and store the full path in a string. The second function is used to obtain the the full path from the string.

Currently this is working because I'm first calling GetPicture and then loadImage.
But I want to "merge" the functions.
So the Javascript would be:

```
function loadImage()
{
    document.getElementById("img").src = Android.GetPicture();
}
```

So I changed the code from WebAppInterface.java to this:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String GetPicture()
{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    ((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);

    return ((MainActivity) mContext).GetURI();
}
```

But it's not working. I think I know why because GetURI is being called before the string URI has been set.

So how do I fix this problem?

---

If somebody knows a better title please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found a solution but I don't know if this is the best way to do it.
So for those who want to know how I fixed it:

I changed the GetPicture method

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String GetPicture()
{
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    ((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);

    while(((MainActivity) mContext).IsFinished == false){}

    return ((MainActivity) mContext).GetURI();
}
```

In MainActivity.java I added a public boolean called IsFinished (set to false) and it is going to be true when the user picked an image (onActivityResult).

So the code will be:

```
public String URI = null;
public boolean IsFinished = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        URI = pickedImage.toString();
        IsFinished = true;
    }
}

public String GetURI()
{
   return URI;
}
```